# SpringMVC spring-web-4.1.1 jar Issue?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

[image: spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE jar file is displayed like this]

I created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse and added all the jars required for Spring MVC which are below.

```
spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-aspects-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-core-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-expression-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE
```

When I tried adding the project in Add and Remove window in eclipse, spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE alone is shown as in the image I uploaded. Can anyone tell me why is it coming like that?

Comment: Have you noticed your webmvc is 4.0.5 while all other jars are more recent to it i.e. 4.1.1 !!!

Comment: but `spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE` is coming in the window rite.....????? and moreover I have added `spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE` jar and removed `spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE` jar and checked. Its still the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly normal and no reason to be worried about. The dialog is not supposed to show all jar files.

It looks exactly the same on my system and everything is working fine.